# Upgrade VS2022 preview to release version

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have Visual Studio 2022 Preview installed and would like to replace it with the release version that went live yesterday.

When I started VS and checked for updates, it let me upgrade from the previous release candidate to Preview 1.0, but not the actual release version.

Is it possible at all to replace the preview with a release version, or do I have to install them side by side (and delete the preview)?

This is the version I have now:
*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.0*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to reinstall. Preview is basically an Insider build. It will continue to update as pre-release even after 2022 releases.

Comment: I didn't need to reinstall, did exactly what @antarct described and it turned my preview version (17.0.0) into the release version (17.0.1), no more 'preview' tags in the splashscreen or about.

Comment: Now you can choose to update directly in the installer. You can try to edit your answer to help more people.

Comment: I had to reinstall. But my version was lagging behind a lot.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT is there anything I have to do to enable this? No matter whether I run the installer from Visual Studio's update prompt or freshly downloaded from the Microsoft web site, I cannot choose any Update Channel other than 'Preview'

Comment: @TomLint Post a separate question with a screenshot showing your question. Try the update [link below.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 45):

You don't have to reinstall anything. Just switch the update channel in Visual Studio Installer (More -> Update settings):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I only get Preview in the Update Channel. I'm afraid that, because I'm already ahead of Current, there's no way to go back without uninstalling.

Comment: Same here i see only the Preview option in the Update channel

Comment: I can confirm the 'Current' update channel is only available when the 'Current' version is ahead of your installed 'Preview' version of Visual Studio

Comment: Why this is not the accepted answer? Worked for me thank you.

Comment: Not working for me, no option for going back to Current/Release/Stable channel

Comment: Seems like I'll have to disable automatic updates and wait for the release version to catch up?

Answer (score 7):

No need to reinstall or to uninstall. Just download the installer of the channel you want and start it. Once the installer finished updating the installer check again the solution from @antarct and it should show you the option to change.

Comment: Confirmed that this is working.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to switch the Update channel, but the context menu still says "Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 **Preview**" and the application still lives in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\**Preview**".

I can't live with that rubbish.  These may be minor, but in what other areas was the upgrade done so poorly?

I'll be uninstalling and reinstalling as soon as I can find the time to waste on something I shouldn't need to do.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to reinstall. From my experience, you just need to run the installer **NOT** from inside visual studio, but from the start menu.

I had switched to preview from release channel for my installation. When I first saw an update notification in visual studio, I opened the installer via the notification and only preview channel was there in the channel list. Then I decided to try the installer from the start menu before hopelessly re-installing as suggested here, the usual full channel list appeared. Then I went back to visual studio and opened the installer from there again, and the channel list was refreshed in there, too. It seems like a metadata refresh problem. Or, maybe the channel data was updated while I was tinkering with it, IDK.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me. From within Visual Studio, "Help -> Check for updates", only "Preview" channel was available. When I launched Visual Studio Installer from the start menu, update settings gave me the choice between "Preview" and "Current" channels. I was able to install a regular release version on top of a preview version in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the release version also if Preview is already installed

Open "VS Installer" --> "Available" --> "Install"

After you selected the version you want to install, you can change the install path and download it

[VS Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRR5f.png)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change the VS 2022 update channel is possible directly inside the Visual Studio UI:

[image]

Just click on "Help" --> "Check for Updates"

The afterwards opened "Visual Studio Installer" dialog looks a bit different to the shown one of this post, but allows to switch the Update Channel between

> Preview
> Current
> LTSC version xx.y

I prefer to use the Long Term Servicing Channel (LTSC) one due to VS stability and with all security updates provided, as informed by the [vendor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-servicing).